# Why the keyboardDismissMode doesn't work?

Tags: swift, uiscrollview

I want my keyboard to hide on an UIScrollView. I used the right proprety I think, but it doesn't work. 
Does someone knows what is the problem ?
Thanks.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var scrollManu: UIScrollView!
    @IBOutlet var txtField: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        scrollManu.keyboardDismissMode = .Interactive
        scrollManu.keyboardDismissMode = .OnDrag

    }
    func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Write this in your `viewDidLoad()`:

```
txtField.delegate = self
```

and change `textField` = `txtField`

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    txtField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}
```

Should work.